# Reading subclass instance of superclass from iostream. How does >> operator know which subclass?

Tags: c++, iostream

I have a superclass Element with multiple subclasses, let's call them A and B.  I want to overload << and >> so I can save and load my objects.

```
class Element
{
public:
   Element();
   int superProperty;
   virtual void write(iostream &out)
   {
      out << superProperty;
   }
   virtual void read(iostream &in)
   {
      in >> superProperty;
   }
};

iostream operator<<(iostream &out, const Element &elt)
{
  elt.write(out);
  return(out);
}

iostream operator>>(iostream &in Element &elt)
{
  elt.read(in);
  return(in);
}

class A : public Element
{
public:
  A();
  int subProperty;
   void write(iostream &out)
   {
      Element::write(out);
      out << subProperty;
   }
   void read(iostream &in)
   {
      Element::read(in);
      in >> subProperty;
   }
};

class B : public Element
{
public:
  B();
  double subProperty;
   void write(iostream &out)
   {
      Element::write(out);
      out << subProperty;
   }
   void read(iostream &in)
   {
      Element::read(in);
      in >> subProperty;
   }
};
```

With these definitions, I can easily write out a file of my Elements, writing each one as

```
iostream mystream;
Element e;
...
mystream << e;
```

Where I'm stuck is reading them back in.  I want it to look like this:

```
iostream mystream;
Element *pe;
...
pe = new Element();  // the problem is right here
mystream >> *pe;
```

But that won't work because I don't know if the element I'm about to read is an Element or an A or a B.  (In my application, I never actually instantiate an Element.  All objects are one of the subclasses.)
I resorted to writing out a char to indicate the class...

```
if (dynamic_cast<A>(e))
{
   out << 'A';
   out << e;
} else if (dynamic_cast<B>(e))
{
  out << 'B';
  out << e;
}
```

and then switch/casing to read like this:

```
    char t;
    Element *pe;
...
    in >> t;
    switch (t)
    {
      case 'A':
        pe = new A;
        break;
      case 'B':
        pe = new B;
        break;
    }
    in >> *pe;
```

but it seems inelegant.

What is a better way to stream my disparate objects?

Comment: I think it is a correct way to do it. But maybe you might want to use some serialization framework that might already provide a way to register types and other features like versionning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In essence, that’s what any serialization solution will boil down to. Elegance may be improved a bit though but using code generation may still be better (serialization frameworks do that).

The dynamic cast can definitely be avoided using a virtual function or a map (type_index to tag [1](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid)). The switch can be replaced with a map (tag to factory) as well. It is even possible (with some template magic) to use the same code to initialize both maps, like:

```cpp
using Factory = void(*)();
struct SerializationInfo {
  char key;
  type_index type;
  Factory factory;
};

template <class T>
SerializationInfo Serializable(char key) // note that SerializationInfo is not a template!
{
    return {key, typeid(T), []() { return new T(); }}; // IIRC captureless lambda is convertible to a function pointer
}

Maps buildSerializationMaps(initializer_list<SerializationInfo>);

buildSerializationMaps({
    Serializable<A>('A'),
    Serializable<B>('B'),
});
```

where `Serializable` is a function template that wraps all the serialization information (key, type id, and factory function) in a standard interface.